# Multiple parameter pass in redirect function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass multiple parameters to a function in same controller.Here is my redirect function when i run this code then show warning.

> Message: Missing argument 2 for Welcome::sendVerificatinEmail()

`redirect('welcome/sendVerificatinEmail/'.$name,$email ,$request_tracking_no);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
redirect('welcome/sendVerificatinEmail/'.$name.'/'.$email.'/'.$request_tracking_no);
```

Your method:

```
function sendVerificatinEmail($name, $email, $request_tracking_no){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Codigniter during redirection all post data will destroy and you have to use session variables to send data.
try this:
I hope help

```
$data = array('param1'=>'ali','param2'=>55);
// store data to flashdata
$this->session->set_flashdata('data',$data);
// redirect  to your controller
redirect('controller/method')  
//in other side
$array = $this->session->flashdata('data');
```

actually Codeigniter uses $_SESSION and you can use directly of sessions instead of flash data like this:

```
//first
$_SESSION['flash'] = implode('@',array(a,b,c));
//then
$flash = $_SESSION['flash'];
$array = explode('@',$flash);
unset($_SESSION['flash']); //free it
```